# Some questions about integral equations.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The equation

$$
u(t) = v(t) + \int_0^t K(t,s,u(s))ds
$$

for $T> 0$, $K:[0,T]\times [0,T]\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ a continous and Lipschitz mapping, has a unique solution.

However, I note that in this theorem the upper limit of the integral is moving, it depends on t. So, for example, how can we ensure the uniqueness and existence of a solution for the equation
$$
f(x) = \frac{2}{3} \cos f(x) + \int_0^1 f(xt)t^3 dt
$$

where the upper limit is static.

Many thanks.

Comment: A hint: apply the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) (aka contraction mapping principle).

Comment: I tried, but I could not bound this thing...

Comment: And also, $C[0,1]$ is not complete, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, it is. And as regards the contractivity it suffices to use the Lagrange theorem and standard estimates for integrals.